# Objective C concatenation keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, key-value-observing

I am attempting to get a thumbnail url using `_valueForKeyPath_` but my json has a dictionary with the path and extension separated. I don't know how to have both path and extension together within `valueForKeyPath`. Any help?

I tried taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054846/keypath-for-first-element-in-embedded-nsarray), but I believe it doesn't solve my issue. Here is how my code looks like thus far:

```
+ (instancetype) characterWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {
    MCUCharacter *character = [[MCUCharacter alloc] init];

    if  ( character ) {

        character.characterImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail.path.extension"]];
        NSLog(@"Character Image URL: %@", character.characterImageURL);
    }

    return character;
}
```

And here is the json :

```
"thumbnail": {
      "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784",
      "extension": "jpg"
}, code here
```

Comment: something like that could / would / should do the job for you: `NSURL *_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail.path"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail.extension"]]];`

Comment: @holex That worked! Please add an answer so I can accept it. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome, I have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to over-explain but you can grab one *value-for-key-path* at the time, so something like that could / would / should do the job for you:

```
NSURL *_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail.path"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail.extension"]]];
```

---

briefly, first it grabs the *path* then appends the *extension* as an actual path-extension to the string, and finally it transforms the string into an `NSURL` object for further use.